# xpath returning multiple elements when searched using Firepath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

IN my application there is a list of elements when searched using xpath (firepath ext). It is as shown below:

```
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button">control_point</i>
<i class="md-icon material-icons remove_class">cancel</i>
<i class="md-icon material-icons remove_class">cancel</i>
<i class="md-icon material-icons remove_class">cancel</i>
<i class="md-icon material-icons remove_class">cancel</i>
<i class="md-icon material-icons remove_class">cancel</i>
<i class="md-icon material-icons remove_class">cancel</i>
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button remove_class">cancel</i>
```

I need to iterate through these and hence I thought of capturing and storing them in

```
@FindAll({@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='add_new_address']/div[5]/i")})
private List<WebElement> ctrlPtORCancelBtn;

public List<WebElement> getCtrlPtORCancelBtn() {
    return ctrlPtORCancelBtn;
}
```

But when I check the size as shown below it's just returning only 1 element.

`ctrlPtORCancelBtn().size()`

I am not able to understand as to why the size of the elements is just 1 and not 8.

How can I deal with this problem. Any help appreciated.

```
<div id="add_new_address" class="uk-grid new_address" data-uk-grid-margin="">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled uk-row-first">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button">control_point</i>
</div>
</div>
<div id="add_new_address" class="uk-grid new_address" data-uk-grid-margin="">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled uk-row-first">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button remove_class">cancel</i>
</div>
</div>
<div id="add_new_address" class="uk-grid new_address" data-uk-grid-margin="">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled uk-row-first">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button remove_class">cancel</i>
</div>
</div>
<div id="add_new_address" class="uk-grid new_address" data-uk-grid-margin="">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled uk-row-first">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button remove_class">cancel</i>
</div>
</div>
<div id="add_new_address" class="uk-grid new_address" data-uk-grid-margin="">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled uk-row-first">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button remove_class">cancel</i>
</div>
</div>
<div id="add_new_address" class="uk-grid new_address" data-uk-grid-margin="">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled uk-row-first">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5 md-input-filled">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
<i class="md-icon material-icons add_button remove_class">cancel</i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, can you update the awnser with the all html code that xpath covers? Starting with the tag that contains the 'add_new_address' id

Comment: yeah plz add the html source code as well that xpath covers

Comment: I have edited my question and included what you asked. Can you please let me if that's what you requested for!!!

Comment: instead of @ FindBy,  use @ FindBys

Comment: Hi  Noor, I have used `@FindBys` & `@FindAll` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inspecting the same thing in HTML panel and see how many elements do u see (non-greyed one's) there are some shortcomings to using FirePath (Although its the best tool i've ever seen so far for locating elements)..HTML panel should give u a clear picture..and if not then try locating elements using `WebDriverWait.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and see how many elements does it returns

Comment: Hi Mrunal, I did that and it is showing all the 8 elements

Comment: Hi Mrunal, Using `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` worked. Thanks my friend.

Comment: if this helped would u consider accepting this as answer..for others looking for such query to find it handy